# Непонятая причина удаления ответа и провал аудита

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, аудит

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/201691

текст ответа:

> Для того, чтобы понять какие данные проходят через серийный порт,
>   протестить его функциональность, можно воспользоваться программой
>   https://www.eltima.com/rs232-testing-software/

С чем может быть связано удаление этого ответа и провал аудита, откуда я знаю реклама это или полезный совет?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Бывают такие короткие ответы со ссылкой. Непонятно, то ли человек рекламирует свой продукт, то ли просто рекомендует инструмент, которым сам успешно воспользовался.

К счастью, вам не нужно было определять, спам это или не спам.
Достаточно было определить другое: удалять ответ или оставить.

Этот ответ состоит из одной ссылки, значит это не ответ.
Его стоит удалить в любом случае.

Comment: Не согласен. Спорный ответ - не могу понять, является ли ссылка названием программы или нет. Если является, то удалять не надо. Если нет, то надо переформулировать так, чтобы являлась.

Comment: @Qwertiy как минимум, в ответе должно быть указано название программы, а не только ссылка. Продвинутый вариант - ссылка под видом названия программы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот процентов 50, что `rs232-testing-software` может оказаться названием, т. к. ссылка ведёт на конкретный продукт, а не на какой-то список. Но какое-то подозрительное название...

Comment: @Qwertiy скоро названия для JS-фреймворков кончатся, тогда и их будут называть как-нибудь подозрительно, например по хешу )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как заранее занять выгодный хэш?

Comment: @Qwertiy знал бы — сам бы занял )))